# PLSQL procedure error

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, pls-00103

I get the below error while executing code

```
create or replace
function contact_restriction_function(obj_schema varchar2, obj_name varchar2)
return varchar2 is
    v_contact_info_visible hr_user_access.contact_info_visible%type;
    begin
    -- Here you can put any business logic for filtering
    select nvl(max(contact_info_visible),'N')
    into v_contact_info_visible
    from hr_user_access
    where user_name = user;

    -- SQL filter / policy predicate
    return ''''||v_contact_info_visible||''' = ''Y'' ';
end;
/
```

after show erros command i got this

```
 show errors    
Errors for FUNCTION CONTACT_RESTRICTION:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
3/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "?" when expecting one of the
         following:
         begin function pragma procedure subtype type 
          current cursor delete
         exists prior external language
```

This is the remaining code:

```
begin
  dbms_rls.add_policy(object_schema => 'HR' ,
                      object_name => 'EMPLOYEES' ,
                      policy_name => 'Contact_Restriction_Policy' ,
                      policy_function => 'contact_restriction_function' ,
                      sec_relevant_cols=>'EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER'Contact Info ,
                      sec_relevant_cols_opt=>dbms_rls.all_rows);
end;
```

below is the actual code which i am executing before show errors:

```
create or replace function contact_restriction(obj_schema varchar2, obj_name varchar2) 
  return varchar2
is
  v_contact_info_visible IN user_access.contact_info_visible%type;
begin
  select nvl(max(contact_info_visible),'N')
    into v_contact_info_visible
    from user_access where username = user;

  return 'v_contact-info_visible ='|| 'Y';
end;
```

Comment: As there is no "?" character in the code you posted I find it tough to diagnose this problem. Perhaps there was some other code that wasn't included?

Comment: this is the remaining code

Comment: begin
    dbms_rls.add_policy(object_schema => 'HR'
        , object_name => 'EMPLOYEES'
        , policy_name => 'Contact_Restriction_Policy'
        , policy_function => 'contact_restriction_function'
        , sec_relevant_cols=>'EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER'Contact Info
        , sec_relevant_cols_opt=>dbms_rls.all_rows);
end;
/

Comment: You've shown code for `contact_restriction_function`, but the error is for `CONTACT_RESTRICTION`. Please show the code you actually executed immediately before calling `show errors`.

Comment: i referred below link http://blog.ctco.lv/articles/introduction-to-oracle-row-level-security-2.html

Comment: below is the actual code which i am executing before show errors          SQL> create or replace
function contact_restriction(obj_schema varchar2, obj_name varchar2)
return varchar2 is
    v_contact_info_visible IN user_access.contact_info_visible%type;
    begin
    select nvl(max(contact_info_visible),'N')
    into v_contact_info_visible
    from user_access
    where username = user;
    return 'v_contact-info_visible ='|| 'Y';
    end;
/

Comment: In the call to `DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY` mentioned in your comment (above) you're passing `policy_function => 'contact_restriction_function'` - but because unquoted identifiers in Oracle default to UPPER CASE this should be `policy_function => 'CONTACT_RESTRICTION_FUNCTION'`. This may not be the source of this problem but may be helpful in the future. Share and enjoy.

Comment: @user3391904 - please put code in the question, not in comments. That still doesn't give the error message with `"?"`; but it will complain about the `IN` in the declaration of `v_contact_info_visible`. Not sure why you're stripped the quote handling from the sample you copied; you've also changed an underscore to a hyphen, which will cause another error.

Comment: @AlexPoole - why don't you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Your original question shows an error message referring to `"?"`, but the code yout posted a as comment would raise a similar error for `"IN"' instead:

```
2/24   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IN" when expecting one of the following:
```

That is because you've used `IN` for a local variable; but `IN`, `OUT` and `IN OUT` are only applicable to stored procedure parameters. You could have declared the function with an explicit `IN` for example, though it is the default anyway:

```
create or replace function contact_restriction(obj_schema IN varchar2, ...
```

So that needs to be removed from the `v_contact_info_visible` declaration. You've linked to an example you're working from, but you've removed a lot of important quotes from that, which will still cause it to fail when executed as a part of a VPD; because `v_contact_info_visible` will be out of scope to the caller. And you have a typo, with a hyphen instead of an underscore.

You need something like:

```
create or replace function contact_restriction(obj_schema varchar2,
  obj_name varchar2)
return varchar2 is
  v_contact_info_visible user_access.contact_info_visible%type;
begin
  select nvl(max(contact_info_visible),'N')
  into v_contact_info_visible
  from user_access
  where username = user;
  return ''''||v_contact_info_visible ||''' =''Y''';
end;
/
```

When called, that will return a string which is either `'N'='Y'` or `'Y'='Y'`. VPD will include that as a filter in the original query, which will either prevent any rows being returned (in the first case) or have no effect and allow all rows that match any other existing conditions to be returned (in the second case).

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the function header is incorrect. It should be:

```
create or replace function contact_restriction(obj_schema IN varchar2, obj_name IN varchar2) 
  return varchar2
is
```

Comment: The `IN`, which I think is all you've changed, is optional; that's the default [parameter mode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS659). It's the `IN` on the next line that is wrong...